# Changed hooks from constructor to init in wordpress plugin class - Not working any more

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop, init

In the previous version ( >5 ) of WordPress the plugin was working correctly. When I transferred it to an updated WordPress (v5.xx) website.

It was giving me an error "visaBooking class does not have init method".

I changed the hooks initialization to init() from _construct(). Now the error is gone but the shortcodes are not working anymore?

```
function visaBooking() { 
    return visaBooking::instance();
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'visaBooking' );



class visaBooking{



    private static $_instance = null;

    private $categories = array();

    private $pricing   = array();

    private $discount  = array();

    private $insurance = array();

    private $pricingDetails = array();



    public static function instance() {

        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) )

            self::$_instance = new self();

        return self::$_instance;

    } // End instance()



    public function __construct(){



        # Read countries json file 

        $countriesFile = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'countries.json';

        $countriesFileResponse = wp_remote_get( $countriesFile );

        $countriesFileBody = json_decode( $countriesFileResponse['body'] , true );



        if( $this->isJson( $countriesFileResponse['body'] ) ){

            $categories = json_decode( $countriesFileResponse['body'] , true );

            if( !empty( $categories ) ){

                foreach( $categories as $category ){

                    switch( $category['Price Type'] ){

                        case 'Medium':

                            $newCategory['medium'][] = $category['Country Codes'];

                        break;



                        case 'Expensive':

                            $newCategory['expensive'][] = $category['Country Codes'];

                        break;



                        case 'Cheaper':

                            $newCategory['cheaper'][] = $category['Country Codes'];

                        break;

                    }

                }

                $this->categories = $newCategory;

            }   

        }



        # Read services json file 

        $file = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'config.json';

        $response = wp_remote_get( $file );

        #$body = json_decode( $response['body'] , true );

        if( $this->isJson( $response['body'] ) ){

            $this->pricing = json_decode( $response['body'] , true );

        } 
    }

    public function init () {


        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'initialization' ) );



        # Get price shortcode

        add_shortcode( 'visa-booking-price' , array( $this, 'visaBookingPrice' ) );



        # Get form shortcode

        add_shortcode( 'visa-booking-form' , array( $this, 'visaBookingForm' ) );



        add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', array( $this, 'modifyPricing' ) );



        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueueScript') );



        add_action('wp_head', array( $this, 'enqueueJs') );



        add_filter( 'gform_enable_field_label_visibility_settings', '__return_true' );



        add_filter('gform_replace_merge_tags', array( $this, 'replace_merge_tag_code' ), 10, 7);



        add_action( 'gform_admin_pre_render', array( $this, 'add_merge_tags' ) );



        add_filter( 'gform_shortcode_conditional', array( $this, 'gform_shortcode_conditional_custom' ), 10, 3 );



        add_shortcode('page_number', function(){

            return $_POST['page_number'];

        });



        add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', array( $this, 'hide_boxed' ), 10, 4 );





        add_shortcode('template_header', function($args){

            ob_start();

            include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/header.php");

            $text = ob_get_clean();

            return do_shortcode($text);

        });



        add_shortcode('order_details', function($args){



            $temp = array(

                'form_id'  => 1,

                'entry_id' => 1,

                'isadmin'  => 'false'

            );



            $args = array_merge( $temp, $args );



            ob_start();



            switch($args['type']){

                case 'flight';

                    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/flight-order-details.php");

                break;



                case 'hotel';

                    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/hotel-order-details.php");

                break;



                case 'flight-hotel';

                    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/flight-hotel-order-details.php");

                break;



                case 'flight-hotel-insurance';

                    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/flight-hotel-insurance-order-details.php");

                break;



                case 'insurance';

                    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/insurance-order-details.php");

                break;

            }



            $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $args['entry_id'] );

            $form = GFAPI::get_form( $args['form_id'] );



            $text = ob_get_clean();

            $text = GFCommon::replace_variables( $text, $form, $entry, false, false, false, 'html' );

            return do_shortcode($text);



        });



        add_shortcode('template_footer', function($args){

            ob_start();

            include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."email-templates/footer.php");

            $text = ob_get_clean();

            return do_shortcode($text);

        });
    }
```

I thought it would run smoothly now but as mentioned above now the short code is not working.

Comment: Do this methods you reference in the class actually exists?

Comment: yes, I have not copied them because of unnecessary code